# Symfony 3: GroupSequence validation groups ignored in validation of form

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I would like to validate a form using group validation and therefore I defined two validation groups. The second group should only be validated if the first group does not already cause violations. So I did this:

```
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null,array('validation_groups' => new GroupSequence(array('group1','group2'))))
        ->add('email', EmailType::class,array('constraints' => array(
            new Assert\Email(array('groups' => array('group1'))),
            new Assert\NotBlank(array('groups' => array('group1'))),
            new CustomAssert\AlreadyRegistered(array('groups' => array('group2'))))))
        ->add('submit',SubmitType::class,array())
        ->getForm();
```

But apparently none of the constraints are validated, the form is valid no matter what I enter in the email field.

What's wrong?

Comment: What is Symfony version you're using?

Comment: @michail_w: It's version 3.2.3

Comment: There is a bug that dates all the way back to 2014 related to GroupSequence (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9939) that is still open and is likely what was impacting your issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the 3.2 documentation you don't need to initiate a new `GroupSequence` object under the `validation_groups`. Try this:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, array(
        'validation_groups' => array('group1','group2')
    ))
    ->add(
        'email', 
        EmailType::class,
        array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\Email(array('groups' => array('group1'))),
                new Assert\NotBlank(array('groups' => array('group1'))),
                new CustomAssert\AlreadyRegistered(array('groups' => array('group2')))
    )))
    ->add(
        'submit',
        SubmitType::class
    )
    ->getForm();
```

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html

Comment: This validates all constraints belonging to the groups listed in 'validation_groups'. But the problem is that all groups are validated, no matter if a previous group has violations already. The validation doesn't stop if group1 has violations. So this way no real "sequence" is defined. But I don't want group2 to be validated always.

If I understand the documentation correctly, it should work the way I wrote it:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10287